# Firebase cloud function getting 404 timeout error

Tags: firebase, next.js, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to run a firebase cloud function. It reads 5k documents and it's taking more than one minute to run in insomnia. When it finally crashes showing a 404 timeout error, how can I fix it? I'm from Brazil and the function region is from the US by default, but I don't believe changing it will help.

I tried making the code cleaner, but didn't help.

This is one of the cloud functions:

```
exports.getTodosPedidos = functions.https.onRequest(
   async (req: RequestType, res: ResponseType) => {
    try {
      const idProjeto = req.query.idProjeto;

      if (!idProjeto) {
        onFailureResponseStructure(res, "ID do Projeto não fornecido.", 404);
      }

      const projeto =
        idProjeto &&
        (await admin.firestore().collection("projetos").doc(idProjeto.toString()).get());

      if (projeto != "" && !projeto?.createTime) {
        onFailureResponseStructure(res, "O projeto fornecido não existe.", 405);
      }

      const snapshot = await admin.firestore().collection("pedidos").get();
      const result = snapshot.docs.map(doc => ({ ...doc.data(), id: doc.id }));

      let idsDosPedidos = result.map(elemento => elemento.id);

      let somaDosArquivos = idsDosPedidos.map(async pedidoId => {
        let bucketRef = await admin
          .storage()
          .bucket()
          .getFiles({
            prefix: `${idProjeto}/arquivos/${pedidoId}/`,
          });
        return bucketRef[0].map(elemento => parseInt(elemento.metadata.size));
      });
      const resultado = await Promise.all(somaDosArquivos);

      onSuccessResponseStructure(res, { resultado, idsDosPedidos });
    } catch (error: any) {
      onFailureResponseStructure(res, error.message, 500);
    }
  }
);

const onSuccessResponseStructure = (res: ResponseType, data: any) => {
  return res.status(200).json({
    status: "OK",
    data,
    messages: [],
    statusCode: "200",
  });
};

const onFailureResponseStructure = (
  res: ResponseType,
  messages: string,
  statusCode: number
) => {
  return res.status(statusCode).json({ status: "ERRO", data: [], messages, statusCode });
};
```

Comment: Time outs in Cloud Functions are many times due to an incorrect management of the Cloud Function life cycle in the code. You should share your entire code as well as the possible error (from the Google Cloud console) for us to be able to help you.

Comment: Could you please share more details around the error you are getting, the code used etc

Comment: Code added, I put one of the functions.

Comment: Each `on*ResponseStructure` call should have `return` in front of it so that the code that follows is guaranteed not to run. Additionally, as you are only using the document IDs that fall under `/pedidos`, you should consider using the [`listDocuments`](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/firestore/latest/CollectionReference.html#listDocuments) method instead as this will only download the path of each document instead of its contents greatly improving speed and reducing the bandwidth consumed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely familiar with firebase.  But other cloud services allow you to increase functions timeout lengths.  It appears firebase does as well...https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/manage-functions#set_timeout_and_memory_allocation

Though for long running tasks you may want to investigate other services.

Comment: Thank you, I increased the timeout to 9 minutes and the memory to 1GB and worked.

Comment: Can you please up vote my answer if it was helpful @RômuloValentim

Comment: I  already did it, but I don't have 15 rep.